# How to send sms alert in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

i'm trying to send a booking confirmation code to a mobile number in form of sms. I did some research and i found some APIs that can be used for this purpose in java. Now im trying to use Twilio but the installation involves maven (https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) .I want to know if there is a better way to send an sms in CN1 or can i just add Twilio jar file into my CN1 library and try whether it will work?

Best Regards

Munir Kolapo Yahya-Imam

IDE: NetBeans

Desktop Windows 7

Simulator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke this from a [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) client you need to use the Twillo REST API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest

The Java API from Twillo is designed for server side Java which you can use on your server.